# Excel VBA Optimizing lengthy IF, Then, Else coding

Tags: excel, vba

I’m building a stats page (Sheet1) based on 8 different cells on Sheet2.

On Sheet2 the top 4 cells (the players name) are on cells D3,G3,J3 and M3.   The bottom row (players winnings) correspond to D4, G4, J4 and M4, respectively.

- D3 is Player name & D4 is winnings for CTP #3
- G3 is Player name & G4 is winnings for CTP #7
- J3 is Player name & J4 is winnings for CTP #13
- M3 is Player name & M4 is winnings for CTP #16.

BTW, this is golf.  CTP is closest to pin on Par 3’s.  Our league has more than 50 players and these results will be posted to the stats page after each round for statistics.  The date is autofill’d on Sheet1 stats page.  This workbook is my “testing” workbook for the CTP stats.

I have a very detailed workbook of other stats that is working fine and once I resolve this issue I will move it to this to the main workbook to add to all the other stats.

With that, I know how to do the VBA to take the values of each CTP player and their winnings from Sheet2 to Sheet1 but it will be on 4 different lines if each CTP has a different winner.  I’ve done the coding for CTP7, 13 and 16 and if they match CTP 3 and will put on the same line.

As you can see the problem comes win a player wins more than one combo of CTP’s for that dates round.  I want the player who won more than one CTP to be on the same line rather than a separate line.

I was able to use “IF”, “Then” and Else statements to make it work but there are so many combinations of a player winning 2 or more CTP’s that it seems crazy to do all the statements required.  Any help is appreciated!

This is my first post on StackOverFlow but it’s been very resourceful for years!

Here is my code in full:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Closest To Pin Stats

'CTP3
Dim stats_Player_CTP3 As Range
Dim stats_Date_CTP3 As Range
Dim stats_Win_CTP3 As Range

Set stats_Player_CTP3 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Set stats_Date_CTP3 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Set stats_Win_CTP3 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)

    stats_Player_CTP3.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value
    stats_Date_CTP3.Value = Date
    stats_Win_CTP3.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4").Value
    
'CTP7=CTP3
Dim stats_Player_CTP7 As Range
Dim stats_Date_CTP7 As Range
Dim stats_Win_CTP7 As Range

Set stats_Player_CTP7 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Set stats_Date_CTP7 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Set stats_Win_CTP7 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G3").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value Then
    Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G4").Value
Else:
    stats_Player_CTP7.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G3").Value
    stats_Date_CTP7.Value = Date
    stats_Win_CTP7.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G4").Value
End If

'CTP13 = CTP3
Dim stats_Player_CTP13 As Range
Dim stats_Date_CTP13 As Range
Dim stats_Win_CTP13 As Range

Set stats_Player_CTP13 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Set stats_Date_CTP13 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Set stats_Win_CTP13 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4)

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J3").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value Then
    Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J4").Value
Else:
    stats_Player_CTP13.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J3").Value
    stats_Date_CTP13.Value = Date
    stats_Win_CTP13.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J4").Value
End If

'CTP16 = CTP 3
Dim stats_Player_CTP16 As Range
Dim stats_Date_CTP16 As Range
Dim stats_Win_CTP16 As Range

Set stats_Player_CTP16 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Set stats_Date_CTP16 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Set stats_Win_CTP16 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 5)

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M3").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value Then
Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M4").Value

Else:
    stats_Player_CTP16.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M3").Value
    stats_Date_CTP16.Value = Date
    stats_Win_CTP16.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M4").Value

End If

MsgBox "Player Update Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: No way i'm gonna read all this. Do us a favour and upload your workbook and provide a link so people can see what you are on about. And In the workbook provide couple of clear examples (on extra example sheets) of the before and after result (actual example not just text explanation).

Comment: Start by declaring and using some worksheet variables - your code is overwhelmed by eg `Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")` over and over, and this hides the gist of what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but your code can be boiled down a lot:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Test_ctp_vba.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ws1.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = ws2.Range("D3").Value
    ws1.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).Value = Date
    ws1.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Value = ws2.Range("D4").Value
    
    checkit ws1, ws2, "G", 3
    checkit ws1, ws2, "J", 4
    checkit ws1, ws2, "M", 5
    
    MsgBox "Player Update Complete!"

End Sub

Sub checkit(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, col As String, colOffset As Long)
    If ws2.Range(col & "3").Value = ws2.Range("D3").Value Then
        ws1.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2, colOffset) = ws2.Range(col & "4").Value
    Else
        ws1.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = ws2.Range(col & "3").Value
        ws1.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).Value = Date
        ws1.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, colOffset).Value = ws2.Range(col & "4").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is a link to the file actually used.  Keep in mind you will be looking at the STATS sheet and the 9 TEAM CALCS sheet.  You can make any changes for testing you see necessary since this is only a copy.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xuwzLYIjKCW5cs_o6Wpuidhkujm-rSso/view?usp=sharing